# Facing issues while integrating "Facebook login" & "Graphi API" in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, authentication

I am integrating Facebook sdk in my android app, the purpose of integration is to get user's profile information like

1. name
2. email
3. id
4. gender
5. birthday

i have registered my app on Facebook developer console using package name, add development key-Hash and make app public for anyone. I have used Graph API for this purpose

```
package info.colabore.freewifi.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import info.colabore.freewifi.R;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginWithFB extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_with_fb);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton btnLoginFb = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnLoginFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("onSuccess");
                String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        // Get facebook data from login
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginWithFB.this, object.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginWithFB.this, object.getString("email"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginWithFB.this, object.getString("gender"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginWithFB.this, object.getString("birthday"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                     catch (JSONException e){
                         Toast.makeText(LoginWithFB.this, "error"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                System.out.println("onError");
                Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        //Facebook login
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }
}
```

when i run my app to my own device(AUSS Zenfone-5) whose development key-hash i have added on Facebook developer console then i get all information(name, email, birthday) but when i run on other devices then calls onError() method. Moreover i have generated release key and when i run release.apk file on my device and other devices then i get this error. "The ey hash does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/...". Help me if anybody knows where's problem.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc2zv.jpg)

Comment: Did you make your application as public in your facebook developer console?

Comment: yes app is public and i have added release key-hash as well on facebook developer console. release key is working fine now but when i use my own fb-account for testing then i get all information(name, email, gender, birthday) but when i try to use other account for testing then just i get name of the user (fb name).

Answer (score 0):

the key hash for release if different from the debug so you have to add that to fb console as well.
Where are you generating the key hash?

Comment: i have added release key hash on fb console but when i use my own fb-account then i get all information but when i try to use other account for testing then just i get name of the user (fb name)..

Comment: You have to add testers in the fb console, if you are still debugging app, fb by default doesn't allow external users